# ¿Cómo acceder a una función externa desde un botón en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, funciones, php7

La función es generar un reporte PDF en el inicio de sesión de mis usuarios registrados y ya lo hago con el siguiente código.

```
<?php  
session_start();
function fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "norma035"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE pin = '{$_SESSION['pin']}' ORDER BY 
pin ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{      
    $output .= '
    <b>-Genero: </b>'.$row["genero"].'<br>
    <b>-Edad en años: </b>'.$row["edad"].'<br>
    <b>-Estado Civil: </b>'.$row["estado_civil"].'<br>
    <b>-Nivel de estudios: </b>'.$row["nivel_estudios"].'<br>
    <b>-Departamento/Sección/Área: </b>'.$row["departamento"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Puesto: </b>'.$row["tipo_puesto"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Contrato: </b>'.$row["tipo_contratacion"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Personal: </b>'.$row["tipo_personal"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Jornada de trabajo: </b>'.$row["tipo_jornada"].'<br>
    <b>-Realiza rotación de turnos: </b>'.$row["rotacion"].'<br>
    <b>-Experiencia (años) en el puesto actual: 
    </b>'.$row["experiencia_actual"].'<br>
    <b>-Tiempo experiencia laboral: </b>'.$row["experiencia_total"].'<br>
    <b>-Nombre Oficina / Centro de Trabajo / Sucursal: 
    </b>'.$row["nombre_oficina"].'<br>
    <b>-Código Postal de la oficina / Centro de Trabajo / Sucursal: 
    </b>'.$row["cp_oficina"].'
  ';  
 }  
 return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
   {  
 require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');  
 $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
 $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
 $obj_pdf->SetTitle("REPORTES.");  
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
$obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
$obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
$obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
$obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);  
$obj_pdf->AddPage();  
$content = '';  
$content .= "";  
$content .= fetch_data();  

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);   
}  
?>
```

El PDF anterior utiliza el campo PIN para generar el reporte por cada inicio de sesión. **Ahora quiero acceder a esa función PDF pero desde un botón que se encuentra en el Panel del super usuario que registra a las empresas.**
El código del botón es el siguiente pero no hace nada, aunque en la URL si logro pasar el el PIN, la página se queda en blanco.

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='reportePDF.php?pin=".$row['pin']."'> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='far fa-file-pdf'> 
</i></button></a></td>";?>
```

En concreto desde el panel de admin. quiero acceder a los reportes de cada uno de los registros y se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ALGUNA SUGERENCIA?

Comment: No se porque borraste la pregunta anterior. Ahora tampoco entiendo el sentido de esta pregunta. Podes armar otra funcion exactamente igual que reciba por parametro el pin que queres, o podes a esa pasarle el pin que queres, asi sea el del usuario logueado u otro, y usar una sola funcion.

Comment: Leí la otra pregunta y no entendí, tampoco ahora entiendo, así que estamos igual @gbianchi. Suri, una sugerencia sería usar Ajax. Así, guardas el valor de `$row['pin']` como `value` o `id` del botón, escuchas el evento *on click* del botón, recoges su value o id y se lo pasas al servidor vía Ajax para generar el PDF. Si no te sirve hacer eso o no puedes, entonces explica mejor el problema para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano Quiero generar el PDF con el botón azul. Este es el botón azul pero no funciono   ------>    <?php echo "<td><a href='reportePDF.php?pin=".$row['pin']."'> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='far fa-file-pdf'> 
</i></button></a></td>";?>                                                               El pdf ya lo genero pero iniciando sesión con email y contraseña desde el login del usuario.

Comment: Elimine la pregunta anterior con la intención de poder sintetizar más la pregunta, pero no se que debo especificar para su comprensión.

Comment: Nosotros no conocemos tu código, por tanto tienes que explicarnos el problema de forma sencilla, intenta hacerlo al principio de la pregunta: *tengo esto, quiero hacer esto, ocurre esto*. Di también la forma en que pasas los datos al servidor, y di si depuraste algo, si verificaste si los datos llegan o no llegan, etc.

Comment: Ahora que ya saben lo que necesito, mencionaré también que al presionar el botón me carga la url del código generarPDF.php con el pin enviado con el botón, peero la página se queda en blanco.